# Get elapsed time to swap img src using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, src

I'd like to get the elapsed time to change the src of an img using JavaScript.  Something like the following:

```
var startTime = new Date().getTime();
document.getElementById('img1').src = someNewUrl;
var elapsedTime = (new Date().getTime()) - startTime;
```

This code apparently is measuring only the time it takes the browser to *set the src attribute* of the img.

What I'd like instead is code that will actually measure the time elapsed until the image is actually loaded.

Is there a way I can accomplish that?  A solution using jQuery would be delightful.

Thanks.

Comment: Be careful about caching. You might not want a cached image to be returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#img1').load(function() {
   ... image has been loaded ...
}
```

You'd have to have the load handler call another function (or do it itself) to do the elapsed time calculation/display.

Comment: Your response assumes the presence of JQuery.  While JQuery is quickly becoming a de-facto standard, the code you pasted won't work unless JQuery is actually loaded.  :)

Comment: And the op says on the last line "A solution using jQuery would be delightful." Learn to read?

Comment: @ddopson the author did say 'A solution using jQuery would be delightful' so I think this i ok.

Comment: @Amir.  oops.  missed that line.  still, always helpful to mention it lest some noob pastes the code and can't figure out why '$' isn't a fuction.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [onload](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_img_onload.asp) method to accomplish this. For example

```
var startTime = new Date().getTime();
document.getElementById('img1').onload = function(){
  var elapsedTime = (new Date().getTime()) - startTime;
}
document.getElementById('img1').src = someNewUrl;
```

With jQuery

```
var startTime = new Date().getTime();
$('#img1').load(function(){
  var elapsedTime = (new Date().getTime()) - startTime
).attr({src: someNewUrl});
```

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on @Marc's answer (using jQuery and [`Date.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) for conciseness):

```
var start = Date.now();

$('#img1').one('load', function()
{
    console.log('Image load took', Date.now() - start, 'ms');
}).attr('src', someNewUrl);
```

---

Without jQuery and whatnot:

```
var img = document.getElementById('img1'),
    start;

img.onload = function ()
{
    var duration = new Date().getTime() - start;
    console.log('Image load took ' + duration + ' ms');
    img.onload = null;
};

start = new Date().getTime();
img.src = someNewUrl;
```

Comment: @Matt +1 This was helpful in putting everything together.  Thanks.